# Access SQL Date Function

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I'm working on editing some SQL code and I've just began learning it. I'm trying to fix an update query so it updates a table's value5 column with a corresponding database value. The value type from the database is a number, which I want to convert to a date and place into my table. The database number is in yyyymmdd format so I've been trying to use datefromparts() which doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas?

```
UPDATE tbl INNER JOIN dB ON 
(dB.value1= tbl.value1 OR 
dB.value2 =tbl.value2 ) AND 
(LEFT(dB.value3 ,5)=tbl.value3 ) AND 
(dB.value4 =tbl.value4 ) 
SET tbl.value5 = DateFromParts(Left(dB.value5,4),Mid(dB.value5,5,2),Right(dB.value5,2))
WHERE tblInvoice.value5 IS NULL;
```

The current program uses the code 
    "SET tbl.value5 = dB.value5"
instead (it runs perfectly fine) and I am having another issue with testing the conversion SQL code (datefromparts()). Because I am converting from numbers to time/date, I have to go into the design view of the target table and change the input data type of the value5 column from numbers to time/date. When I run the query with the conversion SQL code, the query stalls for a bit and no values get updated, leaving me with just a blank value5 column. If I now want to fill in the original number values, I change the SQL code back into its original "SET tbl.value5 = dB.value5", change the input data type from time/date to numbers, and rerun the program. The query stalls and no values are updated, and I am again left with blank columns, even though the same code left me with the corrected update values before the modifications to the SQL and table input Data types. I come from a VBA background and I'm just really confused with how this is working. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with substring instead?

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS ( left('20101231',4), substring('20101231',5,2), right('20101231',2) ) AS Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Access (and MS Jet too) have no DateFromParts function. Using DateSerial instead.

```
SET tbl.value5 = DateSerial(Left(dB.value5, 4), Mid(dB.value5, 5, 2), Right(dB.value5, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you work with T-SQL or Access SQL. In Access, you can use *Format*:

```
SET tbl.value5 = CDate(Format(dB.value5, "@@@@\/@@\/@@"))
```

In T-SQL you could use a similar method.